Can GitLab send notifications to a specific user on Mattermost?
I want to notify a specific Mattermost user when an issue is updated in my GitLab.
I tried using the "Integrations > Mattermost Notifications" feature, but it can only send notifications to a specific group.
I want it to be able to send the message directly to a specific user.
